# Springboot RestController class not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

// this is my Controller.java

```java
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class GreetController {
        @GetMapping("/greet")
        public String greet() {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
}
```

//this is application.java

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.demo"})
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

they are in the same package and when i started server and go to `http://localhost:8080/api/greet` I get a 404 page.

Why and how to fix it?

There is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I work on windows and use intellij http request `GET http://localhost:8080/api/greet`. return 404 code .I checked this [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262140/rest-controller-not-working-in-spring-boot) but not work for me

Comment: Which Spring Boot version? Which OS?

Comment: Also please mention how you are invoking request

Comment: if I write `greet` method inside main class it works fine.

Comment: FWIW I ran your code (main, controller & pom) with jdk-17.0.2_8 and it worked as is.

Comment: I downgraded version of spring to 2.4.3 It worked. Why this weird behavior happened